# Nested this in Stencil.js components

Tags: javascript, typescript, jsx, stenciljs, tsx

I am wondering if there is an easier way to use a nested "this" in a Stencil.js component.

At the moment I am doing this:

```
render() {
    let thisNested = this;

    return <Host>
        {this.images ?

          this.imagesArray.map(function (el) {
            return <img
              // @ts-ignore
              src={thisNested.imageSize ? thisNested.imageSize : el.url}/>
          }) : <slot/>}
      </div>
    </Host>;
  }
```

But I am always repeating myself writing a nested this variable as seen above.

Is there a more elegant way to do what I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use arrow function:

```js
render() {
    return <Host>
        {this.images ?

          this.imagesArray.map((el) => (<img
              // @ts-ignore
              src={this.imageSize || el.url}/>
          )) : <slot/>}
      </div>
    </Host>;
  }
```